# Why does my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop lock up when I do large data transfers between hard drives?

Tags: 14.04, freeze, transfer, io, lockup

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a system that I built from parts.  All software is up to date according to update manager.

System details:

```
Kernel is 3.13.0-39-generic
GCC version 4.8 (i686-linux-gnu)
Xorg version 1.15.1 (30 July 2014  12:19:53AM)
```

Hardware:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 760  @ 2.80GHz
4GB Ram
Ubuntu shares an SSD with Windows 7
```

I have 3 other connected SATA drives of various sizes. The partitions are NTFS with one being EXT4.  I would like to convert most of the NTFS space to EXT4 but these lockups are preventing me from doing that, and I fear I'm loosing data (photos) each time the system crashes during a transfer.

I'm not sure if there is a utility or an easy way for me to post my detailed configuration, I tried to copy my `/etc/fstab` in but it comes out a garbled mess here.

When I copy large files from one sata disk to another the system locks up after about 3 to 5 minutes of activity and drive activity stops. I can switch between windows but nothing is responsive beyond that.  I must shut down by the power button.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will bring me to a console but I cannot log in.

Where do I start to try and figure out what is locking up the system, and if it is fixable?  Windows does not seem to have a problem but I have not booted it in a long time.

`

Comment: If the disks are not failing (no error on `dmesg`) you can try to tweak the buffering: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive (but I don't think that's it, unless you have a very slow drive in the chain). BTW: backup your data.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my own problem by updating the BIOS on my motherboard.

I updated the bios on my Asus P7P55 LX to 1202 from 1003.  Data has been copying between drives successfully now for over 20 minutes.